# an article + a modifier + a conjunction + a modifier + a noun and enumeration of the nouns

Tags: articles

The example: a big and white dog - Is this sentence correct?

And when I enumerate nouns. Like:I like a cat and **Do I need an article here?** dog

Comment: They don't look correct. What do you want them to mean?

Comment: In first example I mean one dog.

Comment: In second example I mean: I like one cat and I like one dog. But I paraphrased it to the sentence: I like (a cat and a dog)

Answer (score 0):

Re the first: If you mean a single dog, yes. If you mean two different dogs, it's very ambiguous (and "incorrect" on such grounds); "a big and a white dog" is good if context allows, "a big dog and a white dog" is better.

Re the second: In informal English this is fine, but it suggests a follow-up: a cat and dog to do what? That are what? Even with the article, the thought sounds incomplete, although the wording is better.